# Jekyll exclude tag from pagination

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have some posts tagged with `foo`, and I want to exclude those from my front page.

I have tried putting this code into the front-page template:

```
<div class="posts">
  {% for post in paginator.posts %}
  {% unless post.tags and post.tags contains "foo" %}

  {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

However this results in the pagination being incorrect.

Here are some example posts:

```
+-------+--------+-----+
| Index |  Post  | Tag |
+-------+--------+-----+
|     1 | Red    | foo |
|     2 | Blue   |     |
|     3 | White  |     |
|     4 | Pink   | foo |
|     5 | Orange |     |
|     6 | Yellow | foo |
|     7 | Beige  | foo |
|     8 | Purple |     |
|     9 | Black  | foo |
+-------+--------+-----+
```

**Actual output:**

1. Page 1: `2, 3, 5`
2. Page 2: `8`

**What I would like:**

1. Page 1: `2, 3, 5, 8`

As you can see it is currently splitting the posts into blocks of 5 and **then** my code filters them - I would like to apply the filtering before the pagination is calculated.

Comment: What happens with other pages generated with the paginator, should they avoid containing posts with that tag also?

Comment: Yes, I don't want them displayed anywhere using the paginator.

Comment: Some clues/ideas: http://www.seanbuscay.com/blog/jekyll-teaser-pager-and-read-more/, https://gist.github.com/yanping/1652964

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done without hacking the paginator plugin, so here we go:

1. remove `gem jekyll-paginate` from `Gemfile`
2. set the needed configuration variables in `_config.yml`:

   ```
    paginate: 2
    paginate_path: "/blog/page:num/"
   ```
3. create the `_plugins` directory
4. copy `pager.rb` and `pagination.rb` to `_plugins/`

   ```
    cd _plugins
    wget https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate/blob/master/lib/jekyll-paginate/pager.rb
    wget https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate/blob/master/lib/jekyll-paginate/pagination.rb
   ```
5. display posts in homepage with the suggested code used in docs

   ```
   <!-- This loops through the paginated posts -->
   {% for post in paginator.posts %}
     <h1><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
     <p class="author">
   <span class="date">{{ post.date }}</span>
     </p>
     <div class="content">
   {{ post.content }}
     </div>
   {% endfor %}

   <h1>  Paginator</h1>
   <!-- Pagination links -->
   <div class="pagination">
     {% if paginator.previous_page %}
   <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous">Previous</a>
     {% else %}
   <span class="previous">Previous</span>
     {% endif %}
     <span class="page_number ">Page: {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages }}</span>
     {% if paginator.next_page %}
   <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}" class="next">Next</a>
     {% else %}
   <span class="next ">Next</span>
     {% endif %}
   </div>
   ```
6. In `pagination.rb` modify the `paginate` function to filter your posts containing the tag `foo`, currently the `all_posts` variable contains all the posts data used to calculate pagination, so we need to remove the ones that contains the tag with:

   ```
          all_posts = all_posts.select do |elem|
            !elem.data['tags'].include? 'foo'
          end
   ```

   Then the function will look like:

   ```
        def paginate(site, page)
          all_posts = site.site_payload['site']['posts'].reject { |post| post['hidden'] }
          all_posts = all_posts.select do |elem|
            !elem.data['tags'].include? 'foo'
          end
          pages = Pager.calculate_pages(all_posts, site.config['paginate'].to_i)
          (1..pages).each do |num_page|
            pager = Pager.new(site, num_page, all_posts, pages)
            if num_page > 1
              newpage = Page.new(site, site.source, page.dir, page.name)
              newpage.pager = pager
              newpage.dir = Pager.paginate_path(site, num_page)
              site.pages << newpage
            else
              page.pager = pager
            end
          end
        end
   ```

Then page 1 will show the desired posts, only the ones not containing the `foo` tag: 2, 3, 5, 8.

Comment: I don't think this handles pagination which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, it didn't mean to handle pagination. From what I understand, It says to merge togheter non foo posts in page one, and foo posts in page 2.

Comment: You've misread the question @marcanuy. I don't want foo posts to show anywhere, but I want to pagination to remain uninterrupted.

Comment: Updated answer filtering posts containing `foo` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `hidden: true` variable in yaml frontmatter for posts not to appear in home page pagination. See [this](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate/issues/6).

While this doesn't filter by tags (you'd need to go through posts one by one and add the option manually) it seems much simpler than the tweaks suggested above.

And pagination for your first and second pages remains correct.

Answer (score 1):

[updated answer]

**Solution 1. New collection**

You reported that the `where` command on the paginator object does not work/recalculate the paging. Therefore, I would advice to save all 'foo' posts in a separate collection. This solves your original problem, but creates a new problem if you want to show all posts combined on another page. If you do not want that, this is the most elegant solution.

**Solution 2. Use Javascript for paging**

Forget about the paginator object and solve this by building you own paging (or infinte scroll) in Javascript, since [pagination is a SEO issue](https://moz.com/blog/pagination-best-practices-for-seo-user-experience) anyway...

*Note: I have created a resource for [Jekyll without plugins](http://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugins). I will add Javascript pagination here too.*

Comment: Thanks @JoostS but this doesn't quite solve the problem. While this removes the pages from page, it doesn't recalculate the pagination.